# How to switch styles for labels using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have checkbox. I want to switch the style of the div containing the checkbox, if the checkbox is checked.

```
<label for="ids">
       <div>
           <img src="img/87_1180.jpg">
           <h4>Name</h4>
           <input name="ids" id="ids" type="checkbox">
       </div>
</label>
```

When user clicks on the label, the checkbox gets checked. I want to add class if the checkbox is checked.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#ids").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("yourClassName");
});
```

Comment: Note that you might want to add the switch `$(this).prop('checked')` to `.toggleClass` - otherwise you could end up with a state mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Josh,

Actually usually the correct way to use a label would be something like this:

```
<label for="ids">Name</label>
<input name="ids" id="ids" type="checkbox" />
```

I don't think it's common practice to put the input within the label according to W3C standards, see:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL

While it might validate the way you wrote the code, it's much harder to control style specifically.

Try this code to change the label:

```
$("#ids").click(function() {
    $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').toggleClass('myClass');
});
```